# Convergence of the series of identically distributed dependent random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$ be identically distributed, positive, not necessarily independent random variables. Consider the series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$$

Is it true that the series diverges with probability 1, or, alternatively, can you construct a counterexample to this?

Comment: No it is not true. See [here](http://www.opentradingsystem.com/quantNotes/Convergence_of_series_of_random_variables_.html) for convergence criteria (Kolmogorov's three series theorem) and the equivalence of a.s. convergence and convergence in probability for series of independent random variables.

Comment: Thank you, Stefanos, that definitely looks like the correct direction to investigate. 
You probably meant "yes, it is true", because the second series from the Three Series Theorem clearly diverges due to the terms being identically distributed, hence the original series should diverge a.s.
The only problem that remains is that the terms are assumed to be independent in the Kolmogorov theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must diverge with probability $1$. Let $p$ be the probability that the sequence converges. Fix any $\epsilon>0$. By dropping the first $N$ entries of the sequence, the series still converges with probability $p$, but the limit of the series will be lower than if all terms are summed. Indeed, it is easy to see that for $N$ large enough,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \epsilon > \sum_{n>N} a_n\right) \ge \frac{1}{2} p.
$$
It follows $\mathbb{P}(a_n < \epsilon) \ge \frac{1}{2}p$ for all $n>N$, and so for all $n$, since $a_n$ are identically distributed. But $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary. Taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ shows $\mathbb{P}(a_n \le 0) \ge \frac{1}{2} p$. Since $a_n > 0$, $p=0$.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! When you say "it is easy to see that for N large enough...", do you mean that the inequality follows from the fact that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability (if you restrict your probability space to the event when the series converges and use probability conditional on that event)? Is there an easier way to see that?

Comment: A basic fact from measure-theoretic probability theory (it's always covered in the first couple pages of probability texts that start with measure theory) is that if $A_n \uparrow A$, then $\mathbb{P}(A_n) \uparrow\mathbb{P}(A)$. In this case, for all $N\ge 1$, let $A_N$ be the set (the "event") on which $\sum_{n>N} a_n < \epsilon$. Let $A$ be the set on which $\sum_n a_n$ converges. Then $A_n \uparrow A$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(A_n) \uparrow p$. Therefore, there's an $N$ for which $\mathbb{P}(A_N) \ge \frac{1}{2}p$, which is the statement I claimed.

Comment: Easy indeed, thanks a lot for the explanation!